# Derivative of exponential function, when the base has '$x$' in it aswell?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know how to find the derivative of an exponential function when the base is a constant, but how do I do it if the base has has an $x$ in it?

> The example I'm having trouble with is  $y=(3x^2-5)^{3x^2+5}$.

**My attempt:** $y'=(3x^2-5)^{3x^2+5} (\ln (3x^2-5)) (-6)$

I have tried using online derivative calculators that show steps but I don't understand how those steps relate to how you would differentiate a exponential function with a constant base eg. $2^{x+5}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct method is as follows:
$$\begin{align}
y=(3x^2-5)^{3x^2+5}&\implies \ln y=\ln (3x^2-5)^{3x^2+5}\\
&\implies  \ln y=(3x^2+5)\ln(3x^2-5)\\
&\implies \frac{y'}{y}=(3x^2+5)\frac{6x}{3x^2-5}+6x\ln(3x^2-5)\\
&\implies y'=y\cdot \bigg[\frac{6x(3x^2+5)}{3x^2-5}+6x\ln(3x^2-5)\bigg]\\
&\implies y'=(3x^2-5)^{3x^2+5}\cdot \bigg[\frac{6x(3x^2+5)}{3x^2-5}+6x\ln(3x^2-5)\bigg]
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you i get it now, but is there any way to relate this to the rule that when y=a^x, y'=a^x (ln(a)) (x'), or does this general rule only apply when the base does not have a variable in it as well?

Comment: @Hamza The rule applies especially when the exponent is variable regardless whether the base is constant or not as long as the base is a positive function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also notice that $y = e^{\log y}$ so $y' = e^y (\log y)'$ (the point is that $log y$ is easier to differentiate than $y$).